# Redirect to custom login page

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have created a custom page for login/registration. Is there any automated way to redirect all wp-login.php calls to that page, or will I need to replace all links manually.

For example, on the comments form, I have this default message:

> You must be **logged in** to post a comment.

The *logged in* links to the

```
http://localhost/wp-login.php?redirect_to=url
```

How can I change this to:

```
http://localhost/my-custom-login-page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect requests to `wp-login.php` to your page:

```
add_action(
  'login_head',
  function() {
    $parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $redirect = site_url('mypage');
    if (!empty($parsed['query'])) {
      $redirect .= '?'.$parsed['query'];
    }
    wp_safe_redirect($redirect,301);
    exit;
  }
);
```

However, `wp-login.php` appears ~34 times in Core on my 3.6.1 install ( `grep -Rn  "wp-login.php" * | wc -l`
 ), and many of those do not appear to be filterable. Actually altering all of those links would take some work and may well involve core hacks.

The `login_url` filter, and the `logout_url` one, will get you part way, but it do not cover all cases.

```
add_action(
  'login_url',
  function($url) {
    return str_replace('wp-login.php','mypage',$url);
  }
);
```

Very rough code. Barely tested. Possibly buggy. Caveat emptor. No refunds.