# Reordering fields in registration form via custom plugin

Tags: user-meta, order, user-registration, validation

I'd like to reorder the fields in the default WP registration form. I'm adding additional fields with my plugin but they are appearing below the username and email fields. My code is below (it's essentially copied and modified from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)).

Does anyone know how I can do that? I assume it involves adding a parameter to the action `register_form`, but I can't find anything in the codex about it. Also, if you have any advice on how I could improve validation as well (if necessary), it would be appreciated as well as I'm trying to learn how to build plugins properly.

```
// Set variables
$theme_name = 'ibm';

/* ****************************************************************** */
                    /* !ADD FORM ELEMENTS */
/* ****************************************************************** */ 

function osu_register_form() {
    // Get and set any values already sent
    $first_name = ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? $_POST['first_name']: '';
    $last_name = ( isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? $_POST['last_name']: ''; ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e('First Name', $theme_name) ?><br />
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($first_name)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="last_name"><?php _e('Last Name', $theme_name) ?><br />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($last_name)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
<?php }

/* ****************************************************************** */
                        /* !VALIDATION */
/* ****************************************************************** */ 

function osu_registration_errors($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', $theme_name) );
    }
    if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'last_name_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a last name.', $theme_name) );
    }
    return $errors;
}


/* ****************************************************************** */
                    /* !SAVE USER META DATA */
/* ****************************************************************** */ 

function osu_user_register($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $_POST['last_name']);
    }
}


// Add functions to WP actions and filters
add_action('register_form','osu_register_form');
add_filter('registration_errors', 'osu_registration_errors', 10, 3);
add_action('user_register', 'osu_user_register');
```

Comment: I don't get the question. If the form is created by your plugin then you control what appears in it and in what order.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry, I meant that this plugin adds additional fields to the standard Wordpress registration form, what I'd like to do is reorder the fields if possible. I've updated my questions to make things clearer.

Comment: Bad news. There isn't any hook to do so. you will have to keep the custom fields below default username and email.

Comment: Ah, that's frustrating. Thanks for clarifying Maruti, I'll have to make do with things as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default login form is not very developer friendly (and it is more developer friendly now than it used to be). If you [browse the source for that page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-login.php) you should be able to convince yourself of that.

Your plugin is not going to be able to manipulate the page the way you hope. A theme could create its own login page, but even that doesn't actually eliminate the default page.

You could attempt to circumvent the login page and replace it via something as in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/118945/21376) but as stated in that answer it seems prone to error as `wp-login.php` is hard-coded into Core source multiple times.

Comment: This seems like the best solution for a bad situation, thanks for adding the details s_ha_dum, I'll probably keep things as is then otherwise I'll try Pippin's approach or plugin which involves rebuilding the login page: http://pippinsplugins.com/creating-custom-front-end-registration-and-login-forms/